# Why my list shows as an empty in app, if it's contain information in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, list, view

Can not display the list in my app.
App accepts array-like empty, but I have info on it and I need to show it. Can you check Ruby people

Controller

```
class GymListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @gym_lists = GymList.all
  end

end
```

Model (this list should be available, but it's not)

```
class GymList < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :users, through: :schedules

  def gym_names
      ["Blink Fitness",
      "24 Hour Fitness",
      "Peloton Studio",
      "Simply Fit",
      "Equinox",
      "Harbor Fitness"]
  end

  def gym_locations
      ["1172 5th Ave, Brooklyn",
      "1556 96 Ave, Brooklyn",
      "356 Lockey St, New York",
      "421 Hudson St, New York",
      "111 Cortney St, New York",
      "37-20 Astoria Blvd, Queens"]
  end

end
```

View

```
<h2>Yours GYM</h2>
<br>
<div>
<% @gym_lists.each do |gym|%>
  <h2><%= gym.name %></h2>
  <h2><%= gym.location %></h2>
  <br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and it shows an empty page.

ruby on rails

Comment: Nowhere in the code you show do you create a `GymList`. Where do you create your `GymList` records? If you think you are trying to access the values returned by `gym_names` and/or `gym_locations`, then you are going about it all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`@gym_lists = GymList.all` gets all GymList records from the databse

- you should use something like
  Controller

```
    class GymListsController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @gym_list = GymList.new
        @gym_lists_name = gym_list.gym_names
        @gym_locations = gym_list.gym_locations  
      end
    end
```

and loop through these two lists in the view and print it
**second solution**

- add these lists to the database then you can use `@gym_lists = GymList.all`

Comment: I think that tutorial will help you a lot https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are many things wrong in your code. You should probably read some documentation about CRUD [this medium post should be a good start](https://medium.com/@nancydo7/ruby-on-rails-crud-tutorial-899117710c7a).

But..regarding your given informations I would like to help you.

- Remove your methods inside your `GymList` model and replace them by:

```rb
NAMES = ["Blink Fitness", "24 Hour Fitness", "Peloton Studio", "Simply Fit", "Equinox", "Harbor Fitness"]
LOCATIONS = ["1172 5th Ave, Brooklyn", "1556 96 Ave, Brooklyn", "356 Lockey St, New York", "421 Hudson St, New York", "111 Cortney St, New York", "37-20 Astoria Blvd, Queens"]
```

- An update your controler with:

```rb
def index
  @gym_lists = GymList::NAMES.zip(GymList::LOCATIONS)
end
```

`zip` is going to create an array of array like that: `[["Blink Fitness", "1172 5th Ave, Brooklyn"], ["24 Hour Fitness", "1556 96 Ave, Brooklyn"], ...]` [doc here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip)

- And update your view with the following code:

**edited answer after the Aleksei Matiushkin's comment**

```rb
<% @gym_lists.each do |name, location|%>
  <h2><%= name %></h2>
  <h2><%= location %></h2>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

But seriously, think about create a model `GymClub` with a `name` and a `location` attributes, and populate your `db` through a `seed.rb`